# Near Protocol NFT add string values mapped to a TokenId. i.e. tokenizing an ipfs hash

Tags: rust, solidity, nearprotocol

I am trying to learn how to use the Near protocol and Rust by recreating my NFT Dapp which mapped string values (ipfs hash's to be exact) which I call a "sketch".
I have already done this successfully using Solidity on Ethereum. example shown at bottom of this page.

**I am simply trying to map string values to a tokenId and subsequently an OwnerId. I have used the boilerplate NFT lib.rs found on the [Near dev NFT website](https://examples.near.org/NFT) and have added my own string mapping for collections of "sketch" which will just contain an ipfs hash value to be used later on the front-end as an image source. What I have for lib.rs is below.**

```
    #![deny(warnings)]

    use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
    use near_sdk::collections::{ TreeMap, UnorderedMap, UnorderedSet };
    use near_sdk::{env, near_bindgen, AccountId};

    #[global_allocator]
    static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

    pub trait NEP4 {
        // Grant the access to the given `accountId` for the given `tokenId`.
        // Requirements:
        // * The caller of the function (`predecessor_id`) should have access to the token.
        fn grant_access(&mut self, escrow_account_id: AccountId);

        // Revoke the access to the given `accountId` for the given `tokenId`.
        // Requirements:
        // * The caller of the function (`predecessor_id`) should have access to the token.
        fn revoke_access(&mut self, escrow_account_id: AccountId);

        // Transfer the given `tokenId` to the given `accountId`. Account `accountId` becomes the new owner.
        // Requirements:
        // * The caller of the function (`predecessor_id`) should have access to the token.
        fn transfer_from(&mut self, owner_id: AccountId, new_owner_id: AccountId, token_id: TokenId); 

        // Transfer the given `tokenId` to the given `accountId`. Account `accountId` becomes the new owner.
        // Requirements:
        // * The caller of the function (`predecessor_id`) should be the owner of the token. Callers who have
        // escrow access should use transfer_from.
        fn transfer(&mut self, new_owner_id: AccountId, token_id: TokenId); 

        // Returns `true` or `false` based on caller of the function (`predecessor_id) having access to the token
        fn check_access(&self, account_id: AccountId) -> bool;

        // Get an individual owner by given `tokenId`.
        fn get_token_owner(&self, token_id: TokenId) -> String;
    }
    /// The token ID type is also defined in the NEP
    pub type TokenId = u64;
    pub type AccountIdHash = Vec<u8>;

    // Begin implementation
    #[near_bindgen]
    #[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
    pub struct NonFungibleTokenBasic {
        pub token_to_account: UnorderedMap<TokenId, AccountId>,
        pub account_gives_access: UnorderedMap<AccountIdHash, UnorderedSet<AccountIdHash>>, // Vec<u8> is sha256 of account, makes it safer and is how fungible token also works
        pub owner_id: AccountId,
        pub sketch: TreeMap<TokenId, String> 
    }

    impl Default for NonFungibleTokenBasic {
        fn default() -> Self {
            panic!("NFT should be initialized before usage")
        }
    }

    #[near_bindgen]
    impl NonFungibleTokenBasic {
        #[init]
        pub fn new(owner_id: AccountId) -> Self {
            assert!(env::is_valid_account_id(owner_id.as_bytes()), "Owner's account ID is invalid.");
            assert!(!env::state_exists(), "Already initialized");
            Self {
                token_to_account: UnorderedMap::new(b"token-belongs-to".to_vec()),
                account_gives_access: UnorderedMap::new(b"gives-access".to_vec()),
                owner_id,
                sketch: TreeMap::new(b"sketch".to_vec()),
            }
        }
    }

    #[near_bindgen]
    impl NonFungibleTokenBasic {
        /// Creates a token for owner_id, doesn't use autoincrement, fails if id is taken
        /// example input for sketch is an ipfs hash ("QmdMuGrMCfvgwg7F6WM8CHev9PJxQ2n3f49ttSGuYfK4Qp")
        pub fn mint_token(&mut self, owner_id: String, token_id: TokenId, sketch: String) {
            // make sure that only the owner can call this funtion
            self.only_owner();
            // Since Map doesn't have `contains` we use match
            let token_check = self.token_to_account.get(&token_id);
            if token_check.is_some() {
                env::panic(b"Token ID already exists.")
            }
            // No token with that ID exists, mint and add token to data structures
            self.token_to_account.insert(&token_id, &owner_id, &sketch);
        }

        /// helper function determining contract ownership
        fn only_owner(&mut self) {
            assert_eq!(env::predecessor_account_id(), self.owner_id, "Only contract owner can call this method.");
        }
    }


        fn transfer(&mut self, new_owner_id: AccountId, token_id: TokenId, sketch: String) {
            let token_owner_account_id = self.get_token_owner(token_id);
            let predecessor = env::predecessor_account_id();
            if predecessor != token_owner_account_id {
                env::panic(b"Attempt to call transfer on tokens belonging to another account.")
            }
            self.token_to_account.insert(&token_id, &new_owner_id, &sketch);
        }
```

If it is any consolation, what I did in Solidity was map "sketch" as strings and push their value while adding the token Id based on the sketch array's length through to the ERC721.sol contract as shown below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Sketch is ERC721, Ownable{
  address payable private admin;
  string[] public sketchs;
  mapping(string => bool) _sketchExists;

  constructor() ERC721("Sketch", "SKETCH") public {
    admin = msg.sender;
  }

  /// @notice mints the ipfs hash passed from the console
  /// @dev example input for _sketch is an ipfs hash ("QmdMuGrMCfvgwg7F6WM8CHev9PJxQ2n3f49ttSGuYfK4Qp")
  function mint(string memory _sketch) public {
    require(!_sketchExists[_sketch]);
    sketchs.push(_sketch);
    uint _id = sketchs.length - 1;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, _id,'');
    _sketchExists[_sketch] = true;
  }

  function transfersketch(address _to, uint _id) public {
      safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _id);
  }
}
```

Am I in the right direction? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!